# Transform a FeatureCollection into a dictionary of properties

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

### Context:

I try to get information from Google Earth Engine using the Python API. I'm sending my GeoPandas dataset as a featurecollection, get some information from images gathered as properties and I want to get them back in my GeoPandas dataset. The simplest way would be to drop the geometry part before the call to `getInfo()`  but I don't find an elegant way to do it.

### Small example

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:1, x:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-04', count:1, x:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:3, x:0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-01', count:2, x:0})
]);
```

and the expected result :

```js
ee.Dictionary({
  "date": ['2020-10-02', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-01'],
  "count": [1, 1, 3, 2],
  "x": [1, 1, 0, 0]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `FeatureCollection` has consistent properties in all its features, then you can create a list of aggregation and use it with column names to build a dictionary:

```js
var keys = collection.first().propertyNames()
var values = keys.map(function(k){return collection.aggregate_array(k)})
var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values)
```